# How do I store a database password temporarily in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm creating a Laravel administration application that can connect to a number of different databases on different servers. I don't want to store the passwords in clear text on the server on the off chance the server is compromised at some point which would give access to every applications' data and not just the local one.

When a user clicks on one of the databases to access, I want them to enter the password for that database and then allow them access for the duration of their session.

I could store the password in a session variable, but I'm not sure if this is secure. What is the safest way to do this?

Comment: best way would be to use laravel5 default encrypt/decrypt mechanism, using strong salt.

Answer (score 1):

You can store it encrypted using the session class.

And you can make the session encrypted, and then store the user pass as encrypted variables.

You can see how to do it here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session

And you can encrypt/decrypt using the Encryption class.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/encryption

```
// Somewhere in your controller
$encrypted = Crypt::encrypt($value);
$request->session()->put('encrypted_pass', $encrypted);

// Later in your controller
$encrypted= $request->session()->get('encrypted_pass', 'default_if_any');
$decrypted = Crypt::decrypt($encrypted);
```

Something like that may work, you should modify it to suit your needs.